# Intuition behind null model for disparity filter algorithm

Tags: statistical-significance, graph-theory, networks

I'm trying to better understand the disparity filter algorithm for weighted networks:

Original paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/106/16/6483

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disparity_filter_algorithm_of_weighted_network

First, the edge weights of each node are normalized by dividing by the sum of weights of edges incident on that node. Then, the authors say that:

> It is based on the following null hypothesis: the normalized weights
>   that correspond to the connections of a certain node of degree k are
>   produced by a random assignment from a uniform distribution. To
>   visualize this process, k − 1 points are distributed with uniform
>   probability in the interval [0,1] so that it ends up divided into k
>   subintervals.

These subintervals, the authors argue are the expected weights of the edges of that node under the null model, and the observed edges are assessed based on the level of departure from these observed weights (by the use of a p-value). In other words, the edges with observed weights significantly different from the expected weights, form the "backbone" of the network.

I don't get the intuition behind this null model. Any help would be much appreciated.